# How to get a selected row id in second while using a pagination in Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a, let's say, 250 rows, that devided into 25 pages. 10 rows on each page. If I'm on the first page, and I click on third row, I get rowIndex = 2. But if I'm on the second page and I click on the first row, logically I'm supposed to get rowIndex of 11th page, so should be rowIndex = 10. But I'm getting rowId = 0. How can I fix that?

Comment: You should be more clear in your query, try to ask what exactly is your issue, what exactly have you tried so far and where are you stuck. the question above might not make sense to the majority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In truth it is correct behaviour. Because when you click on first row, it is first index in table. It doesn't know about data on another pages because they just don't exists (why to load data which you don't need? It can does performance issue)

So if you want behaviour like you are describing, you have to select page number and calculate that.

Something like:

```
rowIndex = getRowIndex ...
page = grid.dataSource.page();
rowIndex = (page - 1) * 10 + rowIndex;
```

[Here demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AbOmo)

Comment: Is there any way to find a solution in ather cases, like, sorting by different columns, and filtering?

Comment: Well, now I don't understand to question. Are you asking how to find out by which columns is grid filtered or sorted?